# Auto increment field while creating Rails association object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, auto-increment, foreign-key-relationship

I am creating Rails model objects by referencing them through association:

```
class MyRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :my_request_addresses
   def self.fill
      self.my_request_addresses.create(parameters)
   end
end
```

`MyRequestAddress` model has one integer field which should indicate route points' order in request. This field should be incremented starting from 1 with each new address created, so the first created address wil be `1`, the second - `2` etc.

Is there some built-in Rails mechanism to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and it's called counter_cache.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html 4.1.2.3